# Nth-child css target last and first 3 child

Tags: css

I have an html like this

```
<ul>
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li>1.2</li>
    <li>1.3</li>
    <ul>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
        <li>2.3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>2.4</li>
        <li>2.5</li>
        <li>2.6</li>
    </ul>
    <li>1.4</li>
    <li>1.5</li>
    <ul>
        <li>2.7</li>
        <li>2.8</li>
        <li>2.9</li>
    </ul>
    <li>1.6</li>
    <li>1.7</li>
    <li>1.8</li>
</ul>
```

How can I target only the last and first 3 child? In my html I want only **1.1**, **1.2**, **1.3**, **1.6**, **1.7** and **1.8** will be target.

This is what I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/fc591x64/) but it target also the li inside of ul's children ul

Comment: Is editing the HTML an option?

Comment: @cjl750 sad to say but it is no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need a way to identify the `ul` you are interested in.  You can add a class or id to the outermost `ul` so that your selectors don't target other `ul`'s.  (If editing the HTML is not an option, you can use the parent element in your selector, and select only direct descendant `ul`'s.)

Next, use the right selectors, to get the first and last 3 children.

To select first 3 children:

```
ul.top > li:nth-child(-n+3)
```

To select last 3 children:

```
ul.top > li:nth-last-child(-n+3)
```

See it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/w93gh2vv/)

Comment: so ill be adding a script to add a class to first ul cause editing the html is not an option

Comment: You can also make sure to target only the top level `ul` by using the element that this `ul` is a descendant of, and selecting only direct descendant `ul` of that element (ex: `body > ul > li`)

Answer (score 0):

I had to target everything but the last and first 3 children.

```css
ul>*:not(:nth-child(-n+3)):not(:nth-last-child(-n+3)) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1.1</li>
  <li>1.2</li>
  <li>1.3</li>
  <ul>
    <li>2.1</li>
    <li>2.2</li>
    <li>2.3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>2.4</li>
    <li>2.5</li>
    <li>2.6</li>
  </ul>
  <li>1.4</li>
  <li>1.5</li>
  <ul>
    <li>2.7</li>
    <li>2.8</li>
    <li>2.9</li>
  </ul>
  <li>1.6</li>
  <li>1.7</li>
  <li>1.8</li>
</ul>
```